# Distinct possibilities for a sum of opposite number combination

Tags: combinatorics

I want to have all the distinct absolute sums of x combinations of (-1,1) and y combinations of (-2,2).

Let's say I sum 3 combinations of (-1,1) and 2 combinations of (-2,2)/
Intuitively, the distinct, absolute, results should be 7, 5, 3, 1 :

`1+1+1+2+2=7
1+1-1+2+2=5
1-1-1+2+2=3
-1-1-1+2+2=1`

I'm having a hard time finding a mathematical representation of this problem, and also an algorithm to best find the distinct results without calculating all the $2^(x+y)$ possible sums.

Comment: By absolute sums you wish only the positive (or zero) sums? And do you want the answer to refer to $x,y$ [numbers of $\pm 1, \pm 2$ used to make the distinct sums]?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean by absolute: a $-2$ result would not be considered distinct from a $2$ result.
I'm looking for a mathematical representation including $x, y$ out of curiosity, but what I'm really looking for ultimately is a good way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum value must be $(x+2y)$ .

Suppose we change one $+1$ to $-1$.
This gives sum of $(x+2y-2)$

When all $+1$ is changed to $-1$, value must be
$(x+2y-2x)=(2y-x)$

Similarly, switching $+2$ to $-2$ makes values such as $(x+2y-4)$ .
Minimum in this case must be to $(x+2y-4y)=(x-2y)$

So, we can generalize now.

Minimum value  is $|2y-x|$ 
Maximum value is $|2y+x|$

All values can be represented as 
$(|2y-x|,|2y-x|+2,\cdots,|2y+x|)$

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your representation of the problem I must admit. If you start by stating that $(x+2y)$ is $x$ times $\pm 1$ added to $2y$ times $\pm 1$, how do you get to switching $+2$ and $-2$ ?

Comment: $x+2y$ is $x$ times $+1$ plus  $y$ times $+2$. if you switch $+1$ to $-1$, the total gets reduced by $2$. Similarly if you switch $+2$ to $-2$, the total gets reduced by $4$.